# Why is DomDocument loadXML not working for me?

Tags: php, domdocument

I have a really simple testcase an am going cross eyed trying to spot what I'm doing wrong. here's the testcase:

```
<?php
$xml = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Contact>
    <Name>Foo Bar</Name>
    <Numbers>
        <Number>9876543210</Number>
        <Number>9876543212</Number>
    </Numbers>
    <Address>
        <Premise>11</Premise>
        <Postcode>ZZ99 9ZZ</Postcode>
    </Address>
</Contact>
XML;

$dom = new domDocument( '1.0', 'utf-8' );
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->recover = true;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$result = $dom->loadXML($xml);
print_r($result);
$errors = libxml_get_errors();
print_r($errors);
$dom->saveXML($xmlContentFormatted);
echo "<pre lang=xml>";
echo $xmlContentFormatted;
echo "</pre><br><br>";  
?>
```

And the output:

```
1Array ( )
```

Comment: Where does `$doc` come from? `$doc->recover = true;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few errors in your code, using `$doc` which isn't defined anywhere - should be `$dom`, also your attempt to output the document using `saveXML` is invalid.  It was trying to use `$xmlContentFormatted` as a context node for the save - again `$xmlContentFormatted` isn't defined anywhere - instead you just use the return value of `saveXML()` as the output...

```
$dom = new DOMDocument( '1.0', 'utf-8' );
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->recover = true;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadXML($xml);
echo "<pre lang=xml>";
echo $dom->saveXML();
echo "</pre><br><br>";
```

Comment: Thank you, that was a dumb mistake.

Comment: All part of learning, I find making mistakes can help learn more than writing loads of working code.